# OData return single node

Tags: json, rest, odata

i have a OData URI where i'm using $expand and $select.

```
http://odataservice.com/TripBookingPrices()?$expand=Trip&$select=TripId,Trip/ItemCode
```

It is working but in the results "Trip" is returning as a collection:

```
{"d": {"results": [
  {
  "__metadata":       {
     "uri": "http://odataservice.com/TripBookingPrices(229)",
     "type": "CodeFirstNamespace.TripBookingPrice"
  },
  "TripId": 46,
  "Trip":       {
     "__metadata":          {
        "uri": "http://odataservice.com/Trips(46)",
        "type": "CodeFirstNamespace.Trip"
     },
     "ItemCode": "ItemCode1"
  }
```

}

It's there a way I can force it to return like this?:

```
{"d": {"results": [
  {
  "__metadata":       {
     "uri": "http://odataservice.com/TripBookingPrices(229)",
     "type": "CodeFirstNamespace.TripBookingPrice"
  },
  "TripId": 46,
  "ItemCode": "ItemCode1"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

no, there is no way to do that from query. But since it is your self-defined function(service operation), you can actually customize the return.